# Hover effect on only one element and not affect the others

Tags: jquery

How to animate only one element *(div)* each time, having class `.box` and not affect the other elements with same class. Something like this :

```
$(.box).hover(function() {
        $(.box).animate({ fontSize : '2rem' });
        $(.box).removeClass("main");
        // other things...
```

html:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

I tried with .next() and .find() but I did not succeed because of my basic level in jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to make a simple code for animate only one element and not affect the others divs with same class like this.

```
$(<selector>)
```

[Selects elements pseudo-based on CSS and some built in keywords by the jQuery team](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

When you attach/bind an event to subscribe to on *all* of your selected elements

```
$('.box').hover(function() { /* do something */ })
```

You basically saying when any of the `.box` class elements are hovered by a mouse execute a function.  jQuery will setup a *context* in which the event is binded with the value of `this` as the raw html element (not a jQuery object) as a feature.  (you can read more about [this here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)). jQuery's selector engine also provides a way to *convert* raw html elements into jQuery object by simply passing them as a selector `$(this)`. Thus some as simple as the following is possible:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.box').hover(
    function() { $(this).addClass('is-hover'); },
    function() { $(this).removeClass('is-hover'); });
});
```

```css
.box{border: 4px solid transparent}
.box.is-hover{border-color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">Test</div>
<div class="box">Test</div>
<div class="box">Test</div>
<div class="box">Test</div>
```

Replacing `$(this)` with `$('.box')` is executing a new query to find all elements with a box class, thus it will affect all the classes with a box class:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.box').hover(
    function() { $('.box').addClass('is-hover'); },
    function() { $('.box').removeClass('is-hover'); });
});
```

```css
.box{border: 4px solid transparent}
.box.is-hover{border-color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">Test</div>
<div class="box">Test</div>
<div class="box">Test</div>
<div class="box">Test</div>
```

Granted if you want to do this a way the more experienced developers would consider best practices, you wouldn't even use jQuery.

```css
.box {
font-size:1rem;
transition: font-size .4s linear;
}
.box:hover {
color:red;
font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>
<div class="box">5</div>
```

Comment: Where is the `animation` part in your answer?

Comment: I think that will work but meVeekay's solution did not work for me ... I got 'a type' undefined error so I have to re-write my code with .addClass / .removeClass to make it cleaner ??

Comment: @JbDel it still misses the `animation` part.

Comment: Your question really has nothing to do with `animation`.  Your question has *everything* to do with understanding why your code runs *whatever jquery code you give it* on *all* elements instead of *the element the event took place on*.  If I give you code that fixes the animation, you haven't learned anything about why your code doesn't actually work.

Comment: Added a much more *best practice* answer to the animation part, since jQuery isn't even needed to do this (and probably shouldn't as CSS is typically responsible for presentation).

Comment: Well, sure its working like a charm with the solution provided by Peter but I am also interested by your cleaner approach and learning in gerenal so I will read these docs.

Comment: jQuery is really powerful.  It's great step towards much more useful technologies like Knockout, React/Redux and Angular.

Answer (score 1):

```
//use 'this' inside an event handler to reference the element being processed for the event
$('.box').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate(...);
    $(this).removeClass(...);
    $(this).whatever...
});
```

Ref. http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/

Comment: Because jQuery supports the fluent api, there is no reason for all those methods to be on separate lines, and re-executing `$(this)` is redundant.  Just `$(this).animate().removeClass().whatever();`.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Due to correct comment this answer has been edited. You could try the following in case you would want to bind different, multiple (e.g. `mouseover focus`) events, benefit of using `.on()`.

```js
$(".box").on({
  mouseover: function() {
      $(this).animate({ fontSize : '2rem' }).addClass('red');
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
      $(this).animate({ fontSize : '1rem' }).removeClass('red');
  }
});
```

```css
.red {
color:#f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>
<div class="box">5</div>
```

In case you specifically want to use `.hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )` then the above snippet would be re-written like in the below snippet...

> Notice the `handlerIn` and `handlerOut` functions being used.

```js
$( ".box" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).animate({ fontSize : '2rem' }).addClass('red');
  }, function() {
    $( this ).animate({ fontSize : '1rem' }).removeClass('red');
  }
);
```

```css
.red {
color:#f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>
<div class="box">5</div>
```

Comment: This is a very poor way to use jQuery.  `.each()` is totally not necessary.  `hover()` simplifies the use of `.on()` and using the event object to access the target is overly complicated compared to using `this`.

Comment: Very nice. "hovered" class is for CSS properties that are not supported by .animate() ?

Comment: @JbDel `.hovered` class was simply used to apply a different color while hovering. It was meant to visually show the change by color also..

Comment: @ErikPhilips i really don't think that it is a poor implementation or jQuery usage. I think it has a really smooth animation, don't you?

Comment: I made no comment on the animation.  I already commented *why* it's a poor usage of jQuery.

Comment: @ErikPhilips the problem is that if you added the `animation` part inside the equation you would see that this is not a poor usage of jQuery. Other than that the usage of `hover()` in your answer indeed simplifies a lot of things and shows a more `clearer` solution. But as written if you add the `animation` part things change. I mean providing `visual` smoothness in animation examples isn't what we want for the end-user?

Comment: Because you don't understand the difference between implementation and result, [here is a much improved *usage/implementation* of jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/erikphilips/97vy0pob/) that has the exact same *result* as your jQuery for the end-user.  Lastly, your answer does not explain in any way, why his code doesn't work.

Comment: @ErikPhilips nice usage using `hover()`. I am sorry for my example, i usually use `on()` in case i want to bind events. But in this case `hover()` does the work greatly. Cheers.